# Add QuickPart Like Date or Title in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to add a QuickPart to my document, just like the image below :

[image: QuickPart Title]

But I can't find how (and I've searched). The only tutorial I found was about adding a text, but without the little label *"Title"* above them.

Is that possible to make a QuickPart like the image, but with *Formation* instead of *Title* ?

Comment: I've added an image. Is it better ?

Comment: Yes. This is it. But I precise, I want the same thing as *Title* with the same type of label (but with *Formation* instead of *Title*). Not just a text insertion.

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/604293/word-2010-repeating-text/604345#604345